# Spring boot: Request method 'PUT' not supported

Tags: rest, put, spring-boot

I am getting a `Request method 'PUT' not supported` error on hitting a **PUT** method on a restful API to upload a file.

Following is the information uploaded to this ticket.

1. Client Log
2. RestController
3. Spring Boot App Config
4. Tomcat log
5. POM.xml

---

### 1. Client Log

```
$ curl -X PUT -T  "/cygdrive/c/a/documents/test.pptx" http://localhost:8080/piranha-storage-service/buckets/gnaval.bucket1/test.pptx
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'PUT' not supported</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Request method 'PUT' not supported</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.52</h3></body></html>
```

---

### 2. RestController

```
package com.acme.piranha.api.impl;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.IOUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.Bucket;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectSummary;
import com.acme.piranha.api.PiranhaStorageService;
import com.acme.piranha.dto.TransferStream;
import com.acme.piranha.exception.PiranhaDataAccessException;
import com.acme.piranha.s3.svc.S3;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/piranha-storage-service")
public class PiranhaStorageServiceRESTImpl implements PiranhaStorageService {

    @Autowired
    S3 s3;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/buckets/{bucketName}/{objectName:.+}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, headers="{Accept=*/*, content-type=multipart/form-data}")
    public @ResponseBody
    String upload(@PathVariable final String bucketName,
            @PathVariable final String objectName,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

        LOG.info("Reached upload. uploading object.");

        try {
            File uploadedFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(uploadedFile));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to upload file!", e);
            }
            final FileInputStream fileUpload = new FileInputStream(uploadedFile);
            final String objectTag = s3.upload(bucketName, objectName, fileUpload);

            LOG.info("Successfully uploaded object to S3, assigned object tag="
                    + objectTag);
            return objectTag;

        } catch (final IOException ioe) {
            LOG.error("Failed upload operation, returning empty string");
            // in case of exception flow return a empty stream.
            return "";

        } catch (final PiranhaDataAccessException pdae) {
            LOG.error("Failed upload operation, returning empty string");
            // in case of exception flow return a empty stream.
            return "";
        }

    }
}
```

---

### 3. Spring Boot App Config

```
package com.acme.piranha.config;

import javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.MultiPartConfigFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.acme.piranha")
public class PiranhaStorageServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
            final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(PiranhaStorageServiceApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(PiranhaStorageServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        MultiPartConfigFactory factory = new MultiPartConfigFactory();
        factory.setMaxFileSize("2MB");
        factory.setMaxRequestSize("2MB");
        return factory.createMultipartConfig();
    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    }
}
```

---

### 4. Tomcat log

```
2014-04-03 12:44:37.159  INFO 5592 --- [lication.main()] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080/http
2014-04-03 12:44:37.168  INFO 5592 --- [lication.main()] c.p.p.c.PiranhaStorageServiceApplication : Started PiranhaStorageServiceApplication in 5.423 seconds (JVM running for 11.60
8)
2014-04-03 12:44:51.995 DEBUG 5592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2014-04-03 12:44:51.997  INFO 5592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2014-04-03 12:44:51.998  INFO 5592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2014-04-03 12:44:51.999 DEBUG 5592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Using MultipartResolver [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServl
etMultipartResolver@1c15b988]
2014-04-03 12:44:52.007 DEBUG 5592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate LocaleResolver with name 'localeResolver': using default [org.s
pringframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver@30ab6fdf]
2014-04-03 12:44:52.014 DEBUG 5592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate ThemeResolver with name 'themeResolver': using default [org.spr
ingframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver@3696a572]
2014-04-03 12:44:52.025 DEBUG 5592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate RequestToViewNameTranslator with name 'viewNameTranslator': usi
ng default [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@57dc2acc]
2014-04-03 12:44:52.032 DEBUG 5592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate FlashMapManager with name 'flashMapManager': using default [org
.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@5e2cc0ac]
2014-04-03 12:44:52.033 DEBUG 5592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Published WebApplicationContext of servlet 'dispatcherServlet' as ServletContext
 attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcherServlet]
2014-04-03 12:44:52.033  INFO 5592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 34 ms
2014-04-03 12:44:52.037 DEBUG 5592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Servlet 'dispatcherServlet' configured successfully
2014-04-03 12:44:52.060 DEBUG 5592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing PUT request for [/pir
anha-storage-service/buckets/gnaval.bucket1/PivotalInstall.pptx]
2014-04-03 12:44:52.065 DEBUG 5592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /piranha-storage-service/buckets/gnaval.bucke
t1/PivotalInstall.pptx
2014-04-03 12:44:52.073 DEBUG 5592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/piranha-storage-service/buckets/gnaval.bucket1
/PivotalInstall.pptx]
2014-04-03 12:44:52.075 DEBUG 5592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/piranha-storage-service/buckets/gnaval.bucket1/P
ivotalInstall.pptx] are [/**]
2014-04-03 12:44:52.076 DEBUG 5592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/piranha-storage-service/buckets/gnaval.buck
et1/test.pptx] are {}
2014-04-03 12:44:52.080 DEBUG 5592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/piranha-storage-service/buckets/gnaval.bucket1/test.pptx] to
 HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@19db7f7e] and 1 interceptor
2014-04-03 12:44:52.083 DEBUG 5592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.Resou
rceHttpRequestHandler@19db7f7e]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'PUT' not supported
2014-04-03 12:44:52.086 DEBUG 5592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.Resou
rceHttpRequestHandler@19db7f7e]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'PUT' not supported
2014-04-03 12:44:52.089  WARN 5592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'PUT' not supported
2014-04-03 12:44:52.096 DEBUG 5592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': a
ssuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2014-04-03 12:44:52.098 DEBUG 5592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

---

### 5. pom.xml

```
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent><dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-service-connector</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.002</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: One comment and one question (neither related to your problem): you don't need the tomcat starter to be explicitly declared, unless you want it in scope=provided (which it isn't). And why are the cloud dependencies scope=provided (who provides them at runtime)?

Comment: yes, cloud dependencies do not need to be in the scope=provided, changed that. Also, removed tomcat started dependency. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Chek you request mapping

if you declare request mapping in class level `@RequestMapping("/api/users")`
then if you declare mapping in method level `@RequestMapping("/api/users/{id}")` this error could occur.

**correct**

```
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
 public class {.....

   @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
   update(....)

}
```

**incorrect** , might cause PUT not supported error

```
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
 public class {.....

   @RequestMapping(value = "/api/users/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
   update(....)

}
```

Comment: Thanks, after looking for hours, this was my issue.

Answer (score 1):

To enable the PUT verb you have to add an interceptor that allows that method in the response header.

Something like that:

```
public class SasAllowOriginInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                           HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
    throws Exception {
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                       "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    return true;
  }
}
```

I don't know how to add an interceptor using spring boot though, and I would be intersted in knowing it :)

Comment: This is something I'd love to know as well.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: your `@RequestMapping` doesn't match the request. The regex probably needs some work.

Comment: I changed @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file to InputStream, it seems to work. Is this ok? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This error happened with me too, I just restarted the server and the error disappeared, the RequestMapping that you've put match the request.

Comment: Please post more details

Answer (score 0):

For adding Interceptor
what you should do is implementing `WebMvcConfigurer` and overriding addInterceptors method.

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfigAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new yourInterceptor());
    }
}
```