# spring Boot -"status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed"

Tags: java, spring-boot

I created a simple Spring Boot REST service using [the guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service), and am getting following error when I POST to `http://localhost:8080/greeting`

> -"status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException","message":"Request method 'POST' not supported",

I didn't find any info on how to solve the error. I am using version 1.3.2.RELEASE and starting Tomcat using `mvn spring-boot:run`.

The guide says that all HTTP methods are allowed by default. So why does it respond that POST is not supported?

How can I get Spring to invoke the controller method when I POST to this URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring boot: Request method 'PUT' not supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847775/spring-boot-request-method-put-not-supported)

Comment: Aside: your question is rather sparse - it may be that the duplicate question will answer it, but if not, would you add more detail? It sounds like a routing problem of some kind (though I don't use Spring nor Java).

Answer (score 11):

As it says in the [Spring REST guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/#_create_a_resource_controller),

> `@RequestMapping` maps all HTTP operations by default

but if, as they suggest, you added a specification of the allowable http methods:

> `@RequestMapping(method=GET)`

then only GETs will be allowed. POSTs will be disallowed.

If you want to allow both GET and POST, but disallow all other [http methods](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), then annotate your controller method thusly:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                        String.format(template, name));
}
```

When you start the application, all the request handler mappings are logged out. You should see a line like this in your log (in the IDE console or command line window):

> s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/greeting],methods=[GET || POST]}" onto public hello.Greeting hello.GreetingController.greeting(java.lang.String)

Also, how are you POSTing? I can recommend the *Advanced REST client* for Google Chrome. If you're posting from a form in your browser, try hitting f12 and examining the Network tab to check that you are POSTing exactly what you think you're POSTing.

POSTing to the wrong URL, e.g. `http://localhost:8080/greetings` instead of `http://localhost:8080/greeting` will result in a *Method Not Allowed* error, although really the error is a typo in the URL, not the choice of HTTP method.

To see more detailed logging for the request processing, create a *src/main/resources* folder alongside your *src/main/java* folder, and create an *application.properties* file in there. Add this line to that file

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

Then, if you try to POST to an unmapped URL, e.g. `/greetings` instead of `/greeting`, you'll see these lines in you log:

> RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /greetings
>   RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/greetings]

Comment: I added this, still getting WARN 885 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported

Comment: @whistling-marmot, thanks for your response, but it still isn't working

Comment: Tried using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847775/spring-boot-request-method-put-not-supported but it does not work.

Comment: Just getting POST request working with Spring Boot is so difficult!!!

Comment: Thank you for the response, its working now, although I dont know what exactly the problem was last time..

Comment: Thank you. This is very informative and helpful.

Comment: i face this problem for @PostMapping without url path.........
it cause all of my css & js file missing ......
after adding url path @PostMapping("/hello").....it working well
thanks.......