# Posting a file to a RESTful Service using RestTemplate

Tags: java, rest, file-upload, spring-boot, jboss

I'm trying to POST an image file from one REST service to another, but I keep getting an error indicating that the required MultipartFile parameter is missing.  Both services are deployed on a JBOSS instance on the same machine.

Adding a MultipartResolver/MultipartConfigElement to the destination service didn't help and neither did adding MessageConverters to the RestTemplate in the sending service.  I think Spring-Boot is taking care of both of those.

I've tried using the org.apache.http classes to do the post instead of RestTemplate and still get the same error.

I tried changing @RequestParam to @RequestPart got a similar error.  Changing it to @RequestBody at least seems to get into the uploadDocument method, but then the file is still null.

I also tried using a Resource, byte array and ByteArrayResource in place of the ClassPathResource and none of that made a difference.

A co-worker suggested it may be a missing JBOSS setting because he built it as an executable with Tomcat embedded and apparently everything worked as expected.

Here's the destination method signature...

## DocumentRestController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadDocument(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
```

The code that executes the POST...

## RBRequestListener.java

```
String binaryPostURL = postURL + returnedDoc.getId();

HttpHeaders requestHeader = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeader.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

MultiValueMap<String, Object> paramaters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
HttpHeaders pictureHeader = new HttpHeaders();
pictureHeader.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
HttpEntity<ClassPathResource> picturePart = new HttpEntity<>(new ClassPathResource("RB_1.png"), pictureHeader);

paramaters.add("file", picturePart);

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(paramaters, requestHeader);

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(binaryPostURL, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
```

The stack trace from the error...

## Stack Trace

```
(http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) Returning HTTP 400 Bad Request: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:251) [spring-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:96) [spring-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:99) [spring-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161) [spring-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128) [spring-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832) [spring-webmvc-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743) [spring-webmvc-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) [spring-webmvc-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869) [spring-webmvc-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) [spring-webmvc-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) [spring-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) [spring-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:120) [spring-boot-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61) [spring-boot-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:95) [spring-boot-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113) [spring-boot-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was an issue with the multipartResolver after all.  In addition to defining a multipart resolver I also needed to disable the Spring-Boot autoconfiguration.  Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29411814/582041) I added the following code to my DocumentApplication class and it is now transferring the file as expected.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MultipartAutoConfiguration.class})

@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver()
{
    return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code, and check content-type = multipart and variable`file` use from where you are sending POST request.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = ("content-type=multipart/*"), produces = "application/json", consumes = "image/*")
public RestResponse save(@@PathVariable("id") String id,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
```

Comment: I had to add 'value = "/{id}"' to the @RequestMapping and couldn't use RestResponse (not sure where that class comes from) but I ended up with the same error ("Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present").